# Self Invoking Function returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get a sum of array injected into a function that loops until all the values are added, the console.log right before the "return" logs the right value, meaning the code works, but when I try to use that function with any array it returns "undefined"...

```
var total = function(arr) {
     console.log(arr);
    if(arr.length > 1) {
      var temp = []
      for(var i=0, len=arr.length-1; i<len; i++) {
        temp.push(arr[i] + arr[i+1]);
      }
      total(temp);
    }
    else {
        console.log(arr.join()); // 48, exectly what I need
      return parseInt(arr.join());
    }
}

var sup = total([1,2,3,4,5]); // undefined
```

Not completely sure how to debug it..

Comment: just add `return` before `total(temp);`

Comment: Because you weren't passing the result of `total(temp)` to the caller.

Comment: @AndreKuznetcov that `return` does not return to the caller of the first invocation of `total`. That returns to `total(temp)`, which in turn is not returned at all. I suggest you learn about how `return` works and how recursion works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `arr.length` is greater than one, you will invoke `total` with the temporary array, however, you don't do anything with this temporary array - you don't return it, or utilize it in any way, so the intermediate results are lost.

In addition - this is not a self invoking function; it is recursion.

Comment: Well, self-calling function))

temp array is passed to the next cycle of function and at the end is returned?..?

Comment: Every cycle its creating the new temp array and passing it to the next cycle untill, the array is 1 element long, and then its suppose to return it...

Comment: " and at the end is returned" yes, the value is returned from the call to `total(temp)`. However, you do not return the value from `total(temp)` to the caller, and so the value is lost. You need to add a return before `total(temp)`.